# Remove characters from a string using preg replace?

Tags: php

I want to replace a number of characters in a string, so I have looked at `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace('/xyz/', '', $val);
```

Yet the above only replaces instances of `xyz` and not individual characters. Here is an example of what I want to happen:

```
preg_replace('/xyz/', '', 'xaybzc'); //abc
preg_replace('/xyz/', '', 'xyzabc'); //abc
preg_replace('/xyz/', '', 'abzxyc'); //abc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern is the literal string. For optional you can use a character class or optional values.

```
preg_replace('/x|y|z/', '', $val);
```

or

```
preg_replace('/[xyz]/', '', $val);
```

what character class you also can use ranges:

```
preg_replace('/[x-z]/', '', $val);
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I wanted to also remove the characters `[]|` from the string?

Comment: You would escape those and put them into either method you'd like. e.g. `preg_replace('/[\[\]|xyz]/', '', $val);` or `preg_replace('/\[|\]|\||x|y|z/', '', $val);` (I find the character class considerably easier to read/use)

Comment: Use the escape character in front of them. Like `[a\[\]b]` or `a|\||b`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `preg_replace` is [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with an array:

```
str_replace(['x', 'y', 'z'], '', 'xaybzc'); // abc
str_replace(['x', 'y', 'z'], '', 'xyzabc'); // abc
str_replace(['x', 'y', 'z'], '', 'abzxyc'); // abc
```

If you want to remove `[`, `]` and `|` as well, simply add them to the array:

```
$replaceArray = ['x', 'y', 'z', '[', ']', '|'];
str_replace($replaceArray, '', 'x[a]b|cyz'); // 'abc'
```